# Doctrine, escape variable field name in DQL

Tags: sql, doctrine, dql

I have a DQL query like:

```
$em->createQuery("
    SELECT r
    FROM WeAdminBundle:FamilyRelation r
    WHERE r.col like :query
")
```

Now I want to change "col" depending on various parameters. How can i achieve this with DQL since the normal setParameter doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you can't the way you want it.

To do it you'd need something like `$dql->setColumn(array('variable_column' => 'some_column_name'))` just as the [`bindColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php) method from PDO, but there's no equivalent method ([bindColum](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/search?q=bindColumn&type=Code) or [setcolumn](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/search?q=setColumn&type=Code)) in Doctrine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setParameter with DQL, as [many examples are provided](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) but for LIKE clauses, make sure the variable is wrapped in `%`.

```
$em->createQuery("
    SELECT r
    FROM WeAdminBundle:FamilyRelation r
    WHERE r.col like :query
")->setParameters(array(
    'query' => '%'.$foo.'%'
))
```

Comment: Yes, for the parameter for the like clause it works, but not for the column name r.col.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question. Do you mean `r.col` becomes something like `r.foo` depending on whatever you set?

Comment: Yes (the entity "r" doesn't change but the field "col")

Answer (score 0):

For use of different parameter instead of col please see below example:

```
$var = "r.col";
```

Here you can change based on condition.

```
$em->createQuery("
    SELECT r
    FROM WeAdminBundle:FamilyRelation r
    WHERE ".$var." like :query
")
```

please have a look it.

Comment: The point of sanitizing a query is to sanitize $var itself, which you are not doing here. if $var comes from user input, this is completely vulnerable.